# Delete a pointer to pointer (as array of arrays)

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I have this in my code:

```
double** desc = new double* [size_out];
for (int i = 0; i < size_out; i++)
    desc[i] = new double [size_in];
```

How do I delete this `desc`?

Should I do:

```
delete [] desc;
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    delete [] desc[i];
delete [] desc;
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    delete [] desc[i];
delete desc;
```

?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340943/c-multi-dimensional-arrays-on-the-heap

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simple rules to follow:

- for each allocation, there has to be a deallocation (ex1 is therefore wrong)
- what was allocated using `new` should be freed using `delete`, using `new[]` should be deallocated using `delete[]` and using `malloc` should be deallocated using `free` (ex3 is therefore wrong)

Conclusion, ex2 is OK.

Answer (score 21):

Your code shouldn't compile. The type of an array new expression is a pointer to the type of array element being created (the value is a pointer to the first element of the allocated array).

So the type of `new double**[size_out]` is `double ***`.

Whenever you use the array form of new, you must use the array form of delete even if you only allocate an array of size one.

```
double*** desc = new double**[size_out];
for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    desc[i] = new double*[size_in];


for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    delete[] desc[i];

delete[] desc;
```

Note that you still haven't allocated any `double`, just pointers.

Did you really want this instead?

```
double** desc = new double*[size_out];
for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    desc[i] = new double[size_in];

for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    delete[] desc[i];

delete[] desc;
```

Answer (score 19):

**Your deletion should mirror your allocation.**

Since you used `new []` to allocate the outer array, and `new []` (in a loop) to allocate the inner arrays, do likewise for deletion. That is: your second solution is correct; `delete []` the inner arrays in a loop, and finally the outer array via `delete []` also.

That said, a (*much*, **much**) better solution in C++ would be to use a nested `std::vector`:

```
// Declaration and initialization:
vector<vector<double> > desc(size_out, vector<double>(size_in));

// No deletion!
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need to use this double**

Answer (score 6):

I would do

```
for (int i=0; i<size_out; i++)
    delete [] desc[i];
delete [] desc;
```

for each array allocated with `new []`, you have a corresponding `delete []`.

And as Rupdolph says: stop using C-arrays, and start using `std::vector`. You will have less bugs (hundred times less bugs).

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 2** is the right one : each cell points to a dynamically allocated array that should be deleted using `delete[]`. Finally, 
the `desc` array itself should be deleted using `delete[]`.

**Bonus solution 4** : avoid using arrays and switch to `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`.