# Am I running out of memory with these 2-dimensional arrays (C++)?

Tags: c++, memory, multidimensional-array, crash, stack-overflow

I try running this C++ code as a Windows console application, but when it starts up, it immediately closes, only giving me a standard "this program has stopped working" error that Windows usually gives me.

The main function of the program is (with a bit of extra code omitted after it):

```
int main() {
    cout << "FIRST LINE";
    int fract[501][501];
    int rfract[501][501];
    int nufract[501][501];
    int nurfract[501][501];
    int snufract[501][501];
    int snurfract[501][501];
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I only have the first 2 arrays, the program runs fine, but if I have any of the other 4 arrays (even just one of them), the program crashes upon start. I am using a computer with 4 GB of RAM, and I haven't been getting any helpful error messages, although it seems like that's the problem.  If I change the sizes of all of them to `[101][101]` (goes from ~1.2 MB to ~50kB) the issue is solved, but I have less space to input functions into them.  Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You could try allocating them at runtime; the heap is usually a lot bigger than the stack.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the stack is MUCH smaller than the size of the heap.  Anything allocated with `new` or `malloc` goes on the heap, but you can fill up the stack very very quickly if you're not careful.

Fitting given the website, you're probably getting a Stack Overflow with so many large arrays.

And to do this, try this code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int sarr2d[5][10];
typedef int dimension[10];
dimension* arr2d = new dimension[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        sarr2d[i][j] = i*j;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        arr2d[i][j] = i*j;
    }
}

// print it out
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        std::cout << arr2d[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

delete [] arr2d;
return 0;
}
```

This is inspired by the question [C++ Multi-dimensional Arrays on the Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340943/c-multi-dimensional-arrays-on-the-heap)

Answer (score 1):

The stack size is usually limited to a rather small default size. If you need a larger stack, you can generally tell that to the linker (in a system specific way).

In this particular case, you can also choose to allocate the variables in static memory space *outside* of the `main` function. That space is generally much larger than the stack space.

```
int fract[501][501];
int rfract[501][501];
int nufract[501][501];
int nurfract[501][501];
int snufract[501][501];
int snurfract[501][501];

int main() {
    cout << "FIRST LINE";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the items on the stack, you can use the /F switch if you are using a Microsoft compiler, or you may be able to specify the size of the stack when you link your program.  I would probably go with the /F switch.  However, this may take away from the heap space (limit on both stack and heap together).

Here is a link on MSDN about increasing the stack size:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/Vsexpressvc/thread/2a5b32b6-683b-4729-92d3-45ed7a89ef3f