# deallocation of a dynamic 2d string array in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble understanding why my delete method is incorrect.

For my matrix creation I have:

```
 43    matrix = new string*[row];
 44    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 45       matrix[i] = new string[col];
 46    }
 47    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 48       for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
 49          matrix[i][j] = array[i][j];
 50          //cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
 51       }
 52       cout << endl;
 53    }
```

Then in my destructor I have:

```
 15    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 16       delete matrix[i];
 17    }
 18    delete matrix;
```

My program crashes on the first entry of deletion

Comment: Try `delete [] matrix[i]` and `delete [] matrix`

Comment: Note: `delete[]` what you `new[]`, and `delete` what you `new`. That said, I've a suspicion that your containing object (of which `matrix` is a member) is not properly implementing the "Rule of Three". If you still have this problem after fixing your array-delete syntax (and I think you will), post the class definition that holds `matrix`.

Comment: Use std::vector. There's no valid reason not to.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams your solution worked. Can you explain why it is 'delete [] matrix[i]' instead of the former?

Comment: @Jack: That's just how the language is specified: array-new, `new[]`, must be matched with array-delete, `delete[]`. The reason is so that each can be separately replaced by user-defined versions. Usually, you don't need to worry about these low-level details, since you'd use `std::vector` to manage your dynamic arrays for you.

Comment: @Jack: it is not a multidimensional array [as you used the tag multidimensional-array], it is a one dimension array of strings not a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you must pair `new[]` with `delete[]`. In these lines:

```
matrix = new string*[row];
matrix[i] = new string[col];
```

You use `new[]`, therefore later on, you must do:

```
delete[] matrix[i];
delete[] matrix;
```

For reference, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198051/why-delete-multidimensionalarray-operator-in-c-does-not-exist).

> When you allocated your two-dimensional array, you really created N
>   one-dimensional arrays. Now each of those have to be deleted, but the
>   system does not know how many of them there are. The size of the
>   top-level array, i.e. the array of pointers to your second-level
>   arrays, is just like any other array in C: its size is not stored by
>   the system.

Here's what valgrind has to say if you use `delete` instead of `delete []`:

```
==30045== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==30045==    at 0x4A05FD6: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==30045==    by 0x400725: main
==30045==  Address 0x4c2e040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 160 alloc'd
==30045==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==30045==    by 0x400715: main
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 matrix = new string*[row];
 for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    matrix[i] =delete[col];
 }
delete[] matrix;
```